# Java native code for Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi2, native-code

I'm interested is it possible to compile Java code to native code so that I can run it on some cheap board like Arduino or Raspberry pi?

What compiler can you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Arduino has only few KB of ram and it's 8 bit CPU - it will not run java.

You can run java on Raspberry Pi: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/oracle-java-on-raspberry-pi

About IDE: you can install IDE directly on Raspberry PI: https://pavelfatin.com/install-intellij-idea-on-raspberry-pi/
 but I would not recommend it - it will be very slow.

I would install IDE on my PC, compile jar file, copy compiled jar to Raspberry Pi and execute it there. You can also remote debug such deployment.

IntelliJ has also free community edition - it should be enough for such simple task and this is the best IDE for java.

One more thing: you can compile java on any machine and run in anywhere, but I see no reason to run in on Raspberry - I'am not sure, but I think that it will lack APIs for controlling Raspberry's custom hardware - in IO Pins.

EDIT: I've found Java API for PI: http://pi4j.com - it looks promising but people are using mostly Python/C++ on PI - this languages has still best support.

Comment: Are there other suitable boards suitable for Java?

Comment: PI is the best one. Oracle has been using it to run JavaFx demos - so it has kind of official support.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino and Raspberry Pi are completely different beasts. That being said, you can run Java on Raspberry Pi as is, given you have a Linux distro with JVM on it.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use JVM. Only Linux and native Java. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what your system's constraints are, and why don't you want to use a JVM on the R-Pi, but in general that's a Java/Linux related question.